# IOS PDF Doesn't Print Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, text, draw

Guys I have a really weird one

I use the following code to create a pdf in my documents directory It has one line of text and 1 image

```
NSString *documentsDirectory =     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"test.pdf";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];

// Create PDF context
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL, NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

// Flip coordinate system
CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(pdfContext);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

// Drawing commands
[@"Hello World!" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:72.0f]];


// DRAW IMAGE
UIImage *anImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sdxlogo.png"];
[self myImage:anImage1 :400 :50 :125 :41];

// Clean up
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

The Pdf Creates fine and when I view on my mac it looks perfect but when I go to print the pdf (from Preview) the Printer preview comes up and it shows the page with text and graphic but when I press print all that is printed on the paper is the graphics and not the text

I have tried different ways of drawing the text but it still won't physically print out

Any Ideas?

Your help greatly appreciated

Mark

Comment: Have you tried saving the pdf and sending it to someone else to print?  Or have you tried printing to a different printer?  Sounds like maybe your printer settings are causing this because you can view the images on the page and it shows up ok on the print preview.

Comment: I can't be the settings as I can print from my iPad from note with a picture and text on it and it prints fine

Comment: My guess would be that something is wrong with the PDF itself, but a) something like Preview on Mac isn't going to tell you that as it's a horribly uncompliant PDF reader and b) we can't help you because you didn't supply a PDF file for us to look at.

Comment: Sorry Guys Big DOH!!! Here it was my printer Cleaned the heads half a dozen times and the text appeared hadn't used this for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word to the wise check your printer before asking questions that make you look an idiot

SORRY

Mark